# Squelize: how to use junction table to create other associates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three basic tables A, B and C. A and B have many-to-many relation. So I use junction table of A_B. C has one-to-many relation to A_B. This is how they are defined when using sequelize.

```
A.associate = function(models) {
    A.belongsToMany(models.B, {
        through: 'A_B',
        as: 'Bs',
        foreignKey: 'a_id'
    });
};
```

B is similar, then C.

```
C.associate = function(models) {
    C.hasMany(models.A_B, {
        as: 'ABs',
        foreignKey: 'c_id'
    });
};
```

But when I run it, I get the following message.

```
Error: C.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

It looks like sequelize does not recognize A_B as valid. Any way to solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch lines of the A_B table, then you need to create a model representing it (it won't be "created" in sequelize when you declare the association in A with through).

Assumptions :

- your table A_B has three columns a_id, b_id and c_id

The code should look something like :

```
const A = sequelize.define('A', {
  id: Sequelize.STRING
})
A.associate = function(models) {
    A.belongsToMany(models.B, {
        through: {
            model: 'A_B',
        },
        as: 'Bs',
        foreignKey: 'a_id',
        otherKey: 'b_id'
    });
}

const B = sequelize.define('B', {
  id: Sequelize.STRING
})

B.associate = function(models) {
    B.belongsToMany(models.A, {
        through: {
            model: 'A_B',
        },
        as: 'As',
        foreignKey: 'b_id',
        otherKey: 'a_id'
    });
}

const A_B = sequelize.define('A_B', {
  a_id: Sequelize.STRING,
  b_id: Sequelize.STRING,
  c_id: Sequelize.STRING
})

const C = sequelize.define('C', {
  id: Sequelize.STRING
})
C.associate = function(models) {
    C.hasMany(models.A_B, {
        as: 'ABs',
        foreignKey: 'c_id'
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works but I need to remove "c_id" from the definition of A_B to fix the error of "Cannot add foreign key constraint".